# Jacobi sum of power residue symbol in Sagemath

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, sagemath

I’m computing Jacobi sum of power residue symbol as follows:

```
def new_residue_symbol(a,P,N):
    if a not in P:
        return K(a).residue_symbol(P,N)
    else:
        return 0

def Jacobi(P,N,j):
    return sum(new_residue_symbol(a,P,N)^j*new_residue_symbol(1-a,P,N)^j for a in (1..P.norm()))

N=3
x=polygen(ZZ,'x')
K.<z>=CyclotomicField(N)
p=-4-3*z
P = K.ideal(p)
Jacobi(P,N,1)
```

Note:$13$ is splits into two prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ . One of them is $\mathfrak{p}=(-4-3\zeta_3)$.

The output is `-3*z - 4` . This is correct. Then let’s change values. Let $N=5, p=7$:

```
def new_residue_symbol(a,P,N):
    if a not in P:
        return K(a).residue_symbol(P,N)
    else:
        return 0

def Jacobi(P,N,j):
    return sum(new_residue_symbol(a,P,N)^j*new_residue_symbol(1-a,P,N)^j for a in (1..P.norm()))


N=5
x=polygen(ZZ,'x')
K.<z>=CyclotomicField(N)
p=7
P = K.ideal(p)
Jacobi(P,N,1)
```

Note:$p=7$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ i.e. inertia degree is $f=4$. So $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]/(p)\cong \mathbb{F}_{7^4}$ is finite field with order $q=7^4$.

The output is `1715`$=5*7^3$.But this is weird since absolute value of the Jacobi sum must be $\sqrt{q}=7^2$. Where is wrong?

Comment: What is ``x`` for?

Comment: The answer $1715$ looks like each of the ``new_residue_symbol(a,P,N)^j*new_residue_symbol(1-a,P,N)^j`` terms evaluates to $1$ (when neither $a$ nor $1-a$ is a multiple of $7$) or $0$ (in all other cases). Not sure if it should, though.

Comment: Do you really want ``a`` to range over ``(1..P.norm())`` as opposed to an actual set of representatives for the quotient ring?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's true only when residue field $\cong \mathbb{F}_p$ i.e. $f=1$ that $1,...,\mathcal{N}(\mathfrak{p})$ are the representatives. So I thought it's ok if I replace `(1..P.norm())` for `P.residue_field()`, but this makes error in latter case (in former case, it success).

Comment: Yes, because ``K(a)`` does not make sense then. Maybe just use ``a`` instead? (And replace ``a not in P`` by ``not a.is_zero()``.)

Comment: Sorry, I’m beginner about Sagemath and Python,  I don’t understand what do you mean( and I don’t know the meaning of `K(a)`). Is it possible to write a whole code?

Comment: You have a ``K(a)`` in the definition of ``new_residue_symbol``. This notation means "apply ``K`` to ``a``", which (since ``K`` is a class implementing a set) results in Sage attempting to convert $a$ into an element of $K$. For example, ``RR(3)`` gives the floating-point real number 3.000..., while ``QQ(3)`` gives the rational number 3/1 (although Sage still prints the latter as 3).

Comment: OK, maybe I figure out about that. Then you meant to replace `K(a).residue_symbol(P,N)` for `a.residue_symbol(P,N)`?

Comment: Yes, and replace ``a not in P`` by ``not a.is_zero()`` or just ``a != 0`` (the former is more direct, even though it looks less so).

Comment: But then sage put error” attributeerror: 'sage.rings.rational.Rational' object has no attribute 'residue_symbol'” in my trial. Perhaps I made mistakes…

Comment: Ah, I see. Sage's ``residue_symbol`` takes an element of the number ring, not of the residue field. You probably want to use the formula for the residue symbol instead: ``a ** ((np-1)//N)``, where ``np = P.norm()``. Note that this should also hold for $a=0$, so you don't need to handle this case separately.

Comment: I redefine `new_residue_symbol` as `def new_residue_symbol(a,P,N):
    for i in (0..N-1):
        if a^((P.norm()-1)//N)-z^i in P:
            return z^i
    else:
            return 0` but sage still made error…

Comment: @darij grinberg
Though I don’t know this is whether the best code or not, I have temporary solution. Please check and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As DaveWitteMorris tell me [here](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/36734), the following code is now temporary answer:

```
def new_residue_symbol(a,P,N):
    if not a.is_zero():
        return a.parent().lift_map()(a).residue_symbol(P,N)
    else:
        return 0

def Jacobi(P,N,i,j):
    return sum(new_residue_symbol(a,P,N)^i*new_residue_symbol(1-a,P,N)^j for a in P.residue_field())

N=5
K.<z>=CyclotomicField(N)
p=7
P =(K.ideal(p).factor())[0][0]#P is prime ideal above p
Jacobi(P,N,1,1)
```

Then the output is $49(=\sqrt{q})$.